# How do you find a lower maximum and upper maximum using pandas?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

If I have a pandas data frame like this:

```
     A    B    C    D    E   F   G
0    1    1   nan  nan   1   1  nan
1    1   nan  nan  nan   1   1  nan
2    1    1    1   nan  nan  1  nan
3    1    1   nan  nan   1   1  nan
```

How do I get the index of the last value before my NaN values and the index of the last overall value?

Such that I get a return of:

(0, B)
(0, F)
(1, A)
(1, F)
(2, C)
(2, F)
(3, B)
(3, F)

as my indices.

Comment: What do you want to happen if `NaN` is the first value in a row?

Comment: Just return the last value. For example if (0, A) and (0, B) were both nan just return (0, F)

Answer (score 1):

For the first requirement, use

```
>>> df.isnull().shift(-1,axis=1).fillna(False).idxmax(1)

0    B
1    A
2    C
3    B
```

For the second,

```
df.notnull().T[::-1].T.idxmax(1)

0    F
1    F
2    F
3    F
```

You can them manipulate these series to get the expected output as you want. For example,

```
>>> list(zip(s1.to_dict().items(), 
             s2.to_dict().items()))

[((0, 'B'), (0, 'F')),
 ((1, 'A'), (1, 'F')),
 ((2, 'C'), (2, 'F')),
 ((3, 'B'), (3, 'F'))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's use `np.where` on a boolean dataframe which indicates the last non null value followed by a NaN in a row.

```
r, c = np.where((df.isnull().shift(-1, axis=1) & df.notnull()).dropna(axis=1))

list(zip(df.index[r], df.columns[c]))
```

Output:

```
[(0, 'B'),
 (0, 'F'),
 (1, 'A'),
 (1, 'F'),
 (2, 'C'),
 (2, 'F'),
 (3, 'B'),
 (3, 'F')]
```

Details:

Use this boolean logic to create a dataframe of booleans show True for the indexes you wish to output.

```
(df.isnull().shift(-1, axis=1) & df.notnull())
```

Output:

```
       A      B      C      D      E     F    G
0  False   True  False  False  False  True  NaN
1   True  False  False  False  False  True  NaN
2  False  False   True  False  False  True  NaN
3  False   True  False  False  False  True  NaN
```

Use `dropna` to remove column G and then use `np.where` to get the index values of the true locations in the above dataframe.  Lastly, use df.index and df.columns to get the labels of the indexes at the locations return by np.where, then `zip` to create tuples and `list`.